# Ajax does not post nicEdit content

Tags: php, ajax

I mam using [nicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com/download.php) and post data using AJAX

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" name="caption" id="caption"></textarea>

$.ajax({
        url: 'submit-gallery.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#progress').hide();
            $('#response_li').show();
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (json.result == 1) {
                $('#response').html('Upload successfully');
                $('#gallery-form')[0].reset();
            } else {
                $('#response').html('Unable to upload');
            }
            $('#response_li').fadeOut(6000);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
```

but value for textarea does not post: here **caption** is the name and id of textarea

and on inspect element i found that that

```
<div class=" nicEdit-main " contenteditable="true" style="width: 347px; margin: 4px; min-height: 45px; overflow: hidden;">
```

[image]

Comment: please post the complete form HTML code~. we can only see the HTML of a textarea and a `formData` variable with no info of how is declared or what data does it has inside.

Comment: on alert(formData) it says: [object FormData]

Comment: try writing `console.log(formData)`. And do let us know how you assign value to it

Comment: okay on inspect element i found that that <div class=" nicEdit-main " contenteditable="true" style="width: 347px; margin: 4px; min-height: 45px; overflow: hidden;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I replaced AJAX post logic with standard form post and now it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the textarea value by using

```
var caption=$("#caption").html();
```

then append this in form data, and capture the posted data.

Comment: then try getting var caption=$("#caption").val();